# C# foreign character handling

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, special-characters

I am trying to read a file and then write it in another format. I have some portuguese characters in my text which are getting mangled or question marks.

I have a sample text that we are reading :

```
PZO DISPONIVEL PARA VENDA CDB PàS P SNA
```

```cs
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test_pcharacters.txt");
// Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-9");
    Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(line);
    byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
    string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
    // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + msg);
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don´t post images of code. Instead directly paste the code here.

Comment: I pasted image so it shows the debugging information.

Comment: How have you created this text file? Is it ANSI, UTF-8, or something else?

Comment: If you use a `StreamReader` instead it should detect the encoding from the file.

Answer (score 1):

When using `File.ReadAllines`, if no specific `Encoding` is specified then the function will default to UTF8.

In your case, explcitily specifying the default encoding (`Encoding.Default`) will resolve the issue:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\users\mparkin\desktop\test_pcharacters.txt", Encoding.Default);
```

The Default encoding uses the current code page where the software is running.  This is likely (but not guaranteed) to be Windows-1252 which includes ANSI characters (such as the one you have in your text file).

Output:

```
Contents of WriteLines2.txt = 
    PZO DISPONIVEL PARA VENDA CDB PàS P SNA
    PZO DISPONIVEL PARA VENDA CDB PàS P SNA
```

As pointed out by @DmitryBychenko, it can be dangerous to rely on Encoding.Default because the returned encoding may differ depending upon the environment.

As an alternative, you could specify the exact code page used to produce your file.  On Windows, this code be 1252, which you can obtain using:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
```

Comment: `Encoding.Default` can be dangerous: it is `UTF-8` in case of  .Net Core and Default Code Page (say, `Windows-1252`) in case of .Net FrameWork; I'd rather put it expilictly: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you, an incredibly important point. I've added some more information about selecting specific code pages rather than relying on the default